# Install more than one MSI files based on user selection in WiX

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

I would like to create a installer (like BootStarper) to achieve following steps using WiX.

- There will be a setup.exe file.
- Upon Runnig this file it has to  open a UI and show the list of softwares (MSI) available for installation.
- The software products are grouped into two Group A or Group B.
- Each group may contain Two or more MSI files (Both internal and third party files)
- Allow user to Choose a group and one or more products to be installed.
- Based on the selection, the products should be silently installed on the local system.

Shall I create a WiX project and display given products(MSI) as its features and can start a deffered custom action to install the seleted ones?

How to author my WiX project to choose the groups and then selected features?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade to WiX 3.6 (Beta) and take a look at the new "Burn" functionality.

You cannot use a deferred custom action to install another MSI because there is a mutex that enforces one running execute sequence per machine.

There is functionality in MSI 4.5 called multi-package transactions however MSI 4.5 may not be already installed on a 2003/XP/Vista Machine so you'd need setup.exe to boostrap it anyways.

Also "concurrent" installs are deprecated and should not be used to do servicing issues.

Comment: WiX 3.6 Burn functionality looks awesome. Experimenting more now. Accepted answer with *****

Answer (score 1):

This is not something you can solve either with the stable WiX release, or Windows Installer.

You will need a separate bootstrapper to launch your MSI files.  as the WiX bootstrapper, [Burn](http://wix.codeplex.com/) is only in the WiX 3.6 beta release and not yet properly documented I would suggest trying something like [dotNetInstaller](http://dotnetinstaller.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Thanks, let me try the dotNetInstaller.

Comment: FWIW, I just use InstallShield since it's setup prereqs are very mature and easy to use.  The suite projects ( equiv to Burn ) are v1 quality and should be better in v2.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter yeah. If you've got a license Installshield is awesome. I use MSI Factory myself, the bootstrapper is pretty mature (not as great as Installshield, but for 1/10th the price I'm not complaining)

Comment: FWIW, InstallShield Limited Edition ( Free to VS users ) also supports setup prereqs.  It's lacking a prereq editor (XML/XSD) though.