# Running another MSI through visual studio installer

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, silent-installer

I want to install MySQL installer msi with my setup.(MySQL installer has to install silently. I am using batch file in custom action to do this.)

However, the problem is that MySQL's msi cannot be run from within main setup.msi it gives out 1618 error(Another installation needs to be completed.) I would like to know an easy way around this.

Background info: MySQL installer unpacks the manifest which contains MySQLInstallerConsole.exe it is then called through another cmd command to install MySQL.

So all I am looking to do is to execute MySQL installer so that it unpacks the manifest. Later I would call the MySQLInstallerConsole.exe to install MySQL through custom action.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Install more than one MSI files based on user selection in WiX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667010/install-more-than-one-msi-files-based-on-user-selection-in-wix)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to mention even more possibilities- some my colleagues mentioned (VS bootstrapper, burn):

1. Just start writing a batch or script for calling the two MSIs after each other.
   Always a good starting point maybe, if you have no experience with MSI.
2. Write your own mini setup.exe bootstrapper with 5 lines of code to do the above.
3. (To be more concrete in "Third party tools":) Buy InstallShield or Advanced Installer or InstallAware, this are the tools with ready GUIs to do such easy bootstrapping.
   I would recommend the second out of them. Starting another MSI are only two clicks. Similar with the other. But there are BIG differences between the three, especially InstallAware is special.

! Mentioned "mini bootstrappers" of those tools are not as powerful as Burn or the others followed:

5. Buy the ready setup suite SetupFactory which can be used as a bootstrapper for MSIs.
6. Use the InstallShield "Suite" project type, if you buy the *Premium* Edition of InstallShield. Costs big bucks, but has a friendly user interface. I was successful using it before some years, but I had to work around a handful of bugs as always with IS (but I guess you will discover bugs with most tools. Way it is.)
7. There (again) Burn would come in handy, you could fix potential bugs or behaviours on your own here ...
   Only it could take you more time in the beginning.

... Of course there may be more.

Comment: 8.  Simplify the problem by changing the requirements.  Put the responsibility to install MySQL on the user and move configuration to the application.  Now the installer is just xcopy.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't an easy work around.  Windows Installer enforces a 1 installation at a time rule through the use of a mutex.  You need to create a bootstrapper / chainer to serialize the installation of your packages.  Visual Studio Deployment Projects don't support this.  I'd suggest looking at Windows Installer XML (WiX) and it's Burn boostrapper / chainer engine.

Comment: I thought of creating a bootstrapper and adding it as a prerequisite in Visual Studio Deployment Project. However, it seems that Bootstrapper Manifest Generator is archived by VS. I would have to learn Wix :(

I have one more doubt: As mentioned in the question MySQL installer has to be installed silently and then I have to call a custom action to execute a executable from the extracted files. Will this be possible through bootstrapping?

Comment: You'd likely bootstrap MySQL then run your installer.  Then in your installer have a custom action that calls the MySQL EXE.  This is assuming the EXE is merely doing configuration and not invoking an MSI.

Comment: Yes the installer extracts files which can then be called for installation. One of them is MySQLInstallerConsole.exe I would call it in custom action. I even checked this with VS Deployment project and it works. Also can you  please confirm whether I would be able to run this bootstrap in silent mode? Also if there is another alternative to Wix.I don't want to learn another language for this.

Comment: Either invest in yourself and retool your skillset or pay a third party to do it for you.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Can you please clarify regarding the silent(quiet) install of bootstrap?

Comment: Burn wouldn't be much of a bootstrapper if it didn't support silent installations.

Comment: I created the bootstrapper however, I would like to make a manifest of it and add it to windows bootstrap list. Am not able to do so. Followed this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429.aspx but doesn't work

Comment: You should accept this answer and post a new question.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is a bit sparse, but in the Visual Studio world the customized bootstrap is the Bootstrap Manifest Generator. The docs start here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429.aspx

and there is an old article here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163899.aspx

but it's not clear how much info and support is available since setup projects were removed from setup projects and then restored.

Comment: I searched a lot but was not able to find Bootstrap Manifest Generator. Currently am trying to create bootstrap with Wix. It did work but now I want to use the bootstrap with Visual Studio Deployment project however, it doesn't show in the prerequisites' list.

Comment: It's way less work to just take the VDPROJ MSI and wrap it with Burn.  Just saying. :)